# Does grass grow when covered in water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing around with the idea of make pistonless automatic street lights in Minecraft. My idea was to use a BUD switch to see if a grass block had grown or died.

I know that if grass is underwater during night it dies, but I dont know if it grows back during the day if it's still underwater.

I would also appreciate it if you had any suggestions for non piston BUD switches, the ones I have been trying to use are not ideal because they send out pulses.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, if you're looking for a light sensor that toggles, then look at this video.

Grass needs light level 9 to grow, so in direct sunlight, with a single layer of water will reduce the light to 12 (1 because it's not the top block and +2 because of the water), so will still grow, but having a second layer will make it now 9, so will mean it takes a while to grow, because it is only just allowed to.

Comment: The light sensor would work for me except it requires a piston which I was trying not to use.

Comment: @johnny1bucket I know, that's why I included the second bit, that first bit was for other people's reference.

Comment: My grass is not dying, I followed ethos labs tutorial (v2) yet no luck, I've tried swapping water for ice as one website suggested, no luck. I am on a Vanilla server though.